# Why Does One SQL Query Work and the Other Does Not?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Please disregard the obvious problems with the manipulation of data in the where clause.  I know!  I'm working on it.  While working on it, though, I discovered that this query runs:

```
SELECT *
FROM PatientDistribution
WHERE InvoiceNumber LIKE'PEX%'
AND ISNUMERIC(CheckNumber) = 1
AND CONVERT(BIGINT,CheckNumber) <> TransactionId
```

And this one does not:

```
SELECT *
FROM PatientDistribution
WHERE InvoiceNumber LIKE'PEX%'
AND CONVERT(BIGINT,CheckNumber) <> TransactionId
AND ISNUMERIC(CheckNumber) = 1
```

The only difference between the two queries is the order of items in the WHERE clause.  I was under the impression that the SQL Server query optimizer would take the worry out of me having to worry about that.

The error returned is:  Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't run? Which error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Can you please post relevant table format/data and output of each query and what is the source/value of `TransactionId` ?

Comment: Sorry, the error is:  Error converting data type varchar to bigint. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the order of the conditions shouldn't matter.

- If `AND ISNUMERIC(CheckNumber) = 1` is checked first and non-matching rows thus dismissed, then `AND CONVERT(BIGINT,CheckNumber) <> TransactionId` will work (for exceptions see scsimon's answer).
- If `AND CONVERT(BIGINT,CheckNumber) <> TransactionId` is processed before `AND ISNUMERIC(CheckNumber) = 1` then you may get an error.

That your first query worked and the second not was a matter of luck. It could just as well have been vice versa.

You can force one condition to be executed before the other:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM PatientDistribution
  WHERE InvoiceNumber LIKE 'PEX%'
  AND ISNUMERIC(CheckNumber) = 1
) num_only
WHERE CONVERT(BIGINT,CheckNumber) <> TransactionId;
```

Comment: I like the way you think!  But that really shouldn't be necessary.  I'm reworking the procedure so that ISNUMERIC isn't necessary.  This seems to expose a problem with the query optimizer.

Comment: No, your queries don't expose any problem with the optimizer. The error you are getting exposes a problem with your queries. The DBMS is free to choose which condition to apply first.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just got lucky that the first one worked, since you are correct that the order of what you list in the where clause does not matter. SQL is a declarative language meaning that you are telling the engine **what** should happen, not **how**. So your queries weren't executed with the same query plan I would suspect. Granted, you can affect what the optimizer does to a certain extent. You'll also notice this type of issue when using a CTE. For example:

```
declare @table table(columnName varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('1')
,('1e4')

;with cte as(
select columnName
from @table
where isnumeric(columnName) = 1)

select
cast(columnName as decimal(32,16))
from cte
```

The above snippet you would assume that the second statement is ran on the results / subset from the CTE statement. However, you can't ensure this will happen and you could still get a type/conversion error on the second statement.

More importantly, you should know that `ISNUMERIC()` is largely misused. People often think that if it returns 1 then it could be converted to a decimal or int. But this isn't the case. It just checks that it's a valid numeric type. For example:

```
select 
   isnumeric('1e4')
   ,isnumeric('$')
   ,isnumeric('1,123,456')
```

**As you can see, these evaluate to true, but would fail the conversion you put in your post.**

Side note, your indexes are likely the reason why the first actually didn't error our.

Comment: To me, please tell me if I'm wrong, both queries are the same.  The only difference is the order of the items in the where clause.

Comment: That is correct @MarkBonafe but your queries weren't executed in the same way / order as you are suspecting.

Comment: That is precisely my question.  Why weren't they executed the same way?  They are exactly the same query.

Comment: Like i said @MarkBonafe, check your execution plan. It's likely your indexes (see my last sentence). Just stop using ISNUMERIC that way and you'll avoid this problem completly.

Comment: Execution plans are identical

Comment: I don't have access to your server, so this is about as far as troubleshooting could go. I've given you a ton of information to explain why this happens, how, and how to avoid it. There's a ton more out there. Don't use ISNUMERIC like this should be your biggest take away.

Comment: Thanks, I was in the middle of making changes so that ISNUMERIC isn't necessary when I stumbled on this.  I was just wondering why.  It's a head scratcher.

Comment: As to "The above snippet you would assume that the second statement is ran on the results / subset from the CTE statement.": Yes, I do. It would be a flaw in the optimizer if it were otherwise.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner run it and see :) More complex CTE queries would force this, but as you will see, you will still get the error in this case.

Comment: I don't doubt that SQL Server's optimizer might be over-optimizing sometimes. All I say is that this is a defect. You CTE query is fine regarding execution order. If the DBMS still executes `CAST` before `ISNUMERIC`, then this is a bug in SQL Server that need be fixed.